# magento 2 set shipping amount for each item

Tags: magento2, cart, quote, cart-items

How I can set shipping amount for each order items.
In my cart, I set for each cart item one shipment but I don't know how I can save it and which model or table saved it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you talking about *Magento cart items shipping amount for each order item*s, then take a look on database table `quote_shipping_rate` and `quote_address`.

**Magento2 does not save each item shipping price at any database table. On the fly means at code level depend on Shipping address/billing address total Shipping rate calculate and it sum save at `quote_shipping_rate` and `quote_address.**

Comment: so if I save shipment amount on quote item database ... can I save shipment for each items ? can you help me for coding this